# Backup and restore files FileTable through SQL Server 2012

Tags: backup, sql-server-2012, restore, filetable

I'm preparing to use the FileTable feature in SQL Server 2012, but I'm unclear about how backups work with this feature:

1) Does a full database backup include FileTable files?

2) How would I perform the restore of a single file, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

1. Does a full database backup include FileTable files?

   - Yes it does include the filetable data. From BOL :
2. When you use SQL Server to back up a FileTable, the FILESTREAM data is backed up with the structured data in the database.

   - If you do not want to back up FILESTREAM data with relational data, you can use a partial backup to exclude FILESTREAM filegroups.
3. How would I perform the restore of a single file, for example?

   - You can use the same restore concept and do a point-in-time restore with STOPAT parameter.

For detailed example refer to (Page 319): [Backup and Restore for FILESTREAM Databases](http://download.red-gate.com/ebooks/SQL/Art_of_SS_Filestream_Sebastian_and_Aelterman.pdf).

Solution given in this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50749/backup-and-restore-filetable-files).